# bash tab completion with spaces

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I'm having a problem with bash-completion when the possible options may contain spaces.

Let's say I want a function which echoes the first argument:

```
function test1() {
        echo $1
}
```

I generate a list of possible completion options (some have spaces, some not), but I don't manage to handle spaces correctly.

```
function pink() {
    # my real-world example generates a similar string using awk and other commands
    echo "nick\ mason syd-barrett david_gilmour roger\ waters richard\ wright"
}

function _test() {
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    use=`pink`
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$use" -- $cur ) )
}
complete -o filenames -F _test test
```

When I try this, I get:

```
$ test <tab><tab>
david_gilmour  nick           roger          waters
mason          richard        syd-barrett    wright
$ test r<tab><tab>
richard  roger    waters   wright
```

which is obviously not what I meant.

If I don't assign an array to `COMPREPLY`, i.e. only `$( compgen -W "$use" -- $cur )`, I get it working if only one option remains:

```
$ test n<tab>
$ test nick\ mason <cursor>
```

But if several options remain, they are all printed within single quotes:

```
$ test r<tab><tab>
$ test 'roger waters
richard wright' <cursor>
```

There must be something wrong with my `COMPREPLY` variable, but I can't figure out what...

(running bash on solaris, in case that makes a difference...)

Comment: You need discrete strings in the array. Like `array=("part one" "part two")`

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed... but I can't figure out how to assign the output of another command to an array, e.g. `array=( $( echo \"part one\" \"part two\" ) )` results in an array with 4 elements, `echo ${array[0]}` will print `"part `.

Comment: There are some [issues](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/186), when completing arguments for options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to process the data from the string you can use Bash's built-in string replacement operator.

```
function _test() {
    local iter use cur
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    use="nick\ mason syd-barrett david_gilmour roger\ waters richard\ wright"
    # swap out escaped spaces temporarily
    use="${use//\\ /___}"
    # split on all spaces
    for iter in $use; do
        # only reply with completions
        if [[ $iter =~ ^$cur ]]; then
            # swap back our escaped spaces
            COMPREPLY+=( "${iter//___/ }" )
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Because you check if `$iter` matches with `^$cur`, spaces also have to be swapped out in `$cur`: `$cur="${use//\\ /___}"`.

Comment: And a final improvement: if `$cur` already starts with a (single or double) quote, that quote must be stripped, and spaces must be escaped manually: `if [[ $cur =~ ^\" || $cur =~ ^\' ]]; then  cur="${cur/#\"/}"; cur="${cur/#\'/}"; cur="${cur/ /\\ }"; fi` (BEFORE swapping out the spaces in `$cur` -- and probably this could be done immediately)

Answer (score 7):

Custom tab-completing words which might include whitespace is annoyingly difficult. And as far as I know there is no elegant solution. Perhaps some future version of `compgen` will be kind enough to produce an array rather than outputting possibilities one line at a time, and even accept the wordlist argument from an array. But until then, the following approach may help.

It's important to understand the problem, which is that `( $(compgen ... ) )` is an array produced by splitting the output of the `compgen` command at the characters in `$IFS`, which by default is any whitespace character. So if `compgen` returns:

```
roger waters
richard wright
```

then `COMPREPLY` will effectively be set to the array `(roger waters richard wright)`, for a total of four possible completions. If you instead use `( "$(compgen ...)")`, then `COMPREPLY` will be set to the array `($'roger waters\nrichard wright')`, which has only one possible completion (with a newline inside the completion). Neither of those are what you want.

If none of the possible completions has a newline character, then you could arrange for the `compgen` return to be split at the newline character by temporarily resetting `IFS` and then restoring it. But I think a more elegant solution is to just use `mapfile`:

```
_test () { 
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]};
    use=`pink`;
    ## See note at end of answer w.r.t. "$cur" ##
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <( compgen -W "$use" -- "$cur" )
}
```

The `mapfile` command places the lines sent by `compgen` to `stdout` into the array `COMPREPLY`. (The `-t` option causes the trailing newline to be removed from each line, which is almost always what you want when you use `mapfile`. See `help mapfile` for more options.)

This doesn't deal with the other annoying part of the problem, which is mangling the wordlist into a form acceptable by `compgen`. Since `compgen` does not allow multiple `-W` options, and nor does it accept an array, the only option is to format a string in a such a way that `bash` word-splitting (with quotes and all) would generate the desired list. In effect, that means manually adding escapes, as you did in your function `pink`:

```
pink() {
    echo "nick\ mason syd-barrett david_gilmour roger\ waters richard\ wright"
}
```

But that's accident-prone and annoying. A nicer solution would allow the specification of the alternatives directly, particularly if the alternatives are being generated in some fashion. A good way of generating alternatives which might include whitespace is to put them into an array. Given an array, you can make good use of `printf`'s `%q` format to produce a properly-quoted input string for `compgen -W`:

```
# This is a proxy for a database query or some such which produces the alternatives
cat >/tmp/pink <<EOP
nick mason
syd-barrett
david_gilmour
roger waters
richard wright
EOP

# Generate an array with the alternatives
mapfile -t pink </tmp/pink

# Use printf to turn the array into a quoted string:
_test () { 
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <( compgen -W "$(printf '%q ' "${pink[@]}")" -- "$2" )
}
```

As written, that completion function does not output completions in a form which will be accepted by bash as single words. In other words, the completion `roger waters` is generated as `roger waters` instead of `roger\ waters`. In the (likely) case that the goal is to produce correctly quoted completions, it is necessary to add escapes a second time, after `compgen` filters the completion list:

```
_test () {
    declare -a completions
    mapfile -t completions < <( compgen -W "$(printf '%q ' "${pink[@]}")" -- "$2" )
    local comp
    COMPREPLY=()
    for comp in "${completions[@]}"; do
        COMPREPLY+=("$(printf "%q" "$comp")")
    done
}
```

Note: I replaced the computation of `$cur` with `$2`, since the function invoked through `complete -F` is passed the command as `$1` and the word being completed as `$2`. (It's also passed the previous word as `$3`.) Also, it's important to quote it, so that it doesn't get word-split on its way into `compgen`.

Comment: I'd rather avoid writing a file to `/tmp`, I don't really understand why you'd need that... I generate my alternatives using `awk`, I can add quotes there.

Comment: @geronimo: I'm not recommending that you write a file to `/tmp`. It was just a way to abstract away from the actual construction of the alternatives. In practice, you would use `mapfile -t pink < <(awk ...)`. The point is that `printf %q` understands bash quoting better than you or I, since it is part of bash, so it's easier and more reliable than roll-your-own quoting.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I won't be able to use mapfile, though: `-bash: mapfile: command not found` :-(  I think I'll have to combine your solution with @amphetamachine's...

Comment: Further testing learned me this: your `mangle` function looks very promising, but is only useful when combined with the `mapfile` function (apparently only since bash 4, I'll ask my sysadmin why we're still using bash from 2007).

Comment: This is very clever!  I only have one issue in using it though.  My completions include the embedded space as expected, but that space is neither escaped nor quoted to protect it on the cmd-line I'm composing with tab-completion.  What's the best way to handle that?  For now I'm using `mangle() {
    printf '"%q" ' "${@}"
}`.  Note the extra quoting around `%q`.  Is that appropriate?

Comment: @JFlo: No, adding extra quotes to a string printed with `%q` will produce quoting errors in some cases. What you need to do is to mangle twice: the first time, to produce the argument to `compgen`, and the second time, after you produce the array from the output of `compgen`, to requote the generated completions.

Comment: @JFlo: Edited that into my answer.

Comment: @rici Thanks for incorporating those changes, though I see they're a bit different.  Was there anything wrong with my approach, which seemingly had the advantage of not needing the loop?

Comment: @JFlo: not really. I just thought the loop was clearer, and possibly more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this crazy contraption draws heavily on **rici**’s solution, and not only fully works, but also quotes any completions that need it, and *only* those.

```
pink() {
    # simulating actual awk output
    echo "nick mason"
    echo "syd-barrett"
    echo "david_gilmour"
    echo "roger waters"
    echo "richard wright"
}

_test() {
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  mapfile -t patterns < <( pink )
  mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <( compgen -W "$( printf '%q ' "${patterns[@]}" )" -- "$cur" | awk '/ / { print "\""$0"\"" } /^[^ ]+$/ { print $0 }' )
}

complete -F _test test
```

So as far as I could test it, it fully implements `ls`-like behavior, minus the path-specific parts.

#### Verbose example

Here’s a more verbose version of the `_test` function, so it becomes a bit more understandable:

```
_test() {
  local cur escapedPatterns
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  mapfile -t patterns < <( pink )
  escapedPatterns="$( printf '%q ' "${patterns[@]}" )"
  mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <( compgen -W "$escapedPatterns" -- "$cur" | quoteIfNeeded )
}

quoteIfNeeded() {
  # Only if it contains spaces. Otherwise return as-is.
  awk '/ / { print "\""$0"\"" } /^[^ ]+$/ { print $0 }'
}
```

None of this is even remotely optimized for efficiency. Then again, this is only tab completion, and it’s not causing a noticeable delay for any reasonably large list  of completions.

#### It works by:

1. Pulling the `awk` output into an array, using `mapfile`.
2. Escaping the array and putting it into a string.
3. Having a single space behind the `%q` as a separation marker.
4. Quoting `$cur`, Very important!
5. Quoting the *output* of `compgen`. And only if it contains spaces.
6. Feeding that output into COMPREPLY, using *another* `mapfile` call.
7. *Not* using `-o filenames`.

And it *only* works with all those tricks. It fails if even a single one is missing. Trust me; I’ve tried. ;)

Comment: It might be good to quote all completions, because completing 'nicklas' and 'nick mason' from 'n' would work better then.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't be quoting anything. Just make sure that COMPREPLY has the proper values. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `mapfile` available. The following seems a bit simpler than the other answers and worked fine for me:

```sh
_completion() {
  local CUR=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local OPT
  local -a OPTS

  while read -r OPT; do
    local OPT_ESC
    OPT_ESC="$(printf '%q' "$OPT")"
    [[ -z "$CUR" ]] || [[ "$OPT_ESC" == "$CUR"* ]] && \
      COMPREPLY+=("$OPT_ESC")
  done < "${TOKEN_FILE}"
}
```

- Each line in `TOKEN_FILE` is a completion option.
- Replace `"${TOKEN_FILE}"` with `<(token_generator)` where `token_genorator` is some command than generates completion tokens, on line at a time.
- The `printf '%q'` gives us a bash-escaped string suitable for consumption on the command line as a single token.

So, if `TOKEN_FILE` is:

```
option a
another option
an option with many spaces
```

Then tab-completing would print:

```
an\ option\ with\ many\ spaces     another\ option
option\ a
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with OP's code is just the expansion of the output of `compgen`. It uses shell's *sloppy* expansion `COMPREPLY=(...)` which breaks on every space.

Replace that line with

```bash
mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <( compgen -W "$use" -- $cur )
```

and the code works fine.

Note that [*Shellcheck*](https://www.shellcheck.net) would have complained about that `COMPREPLY=(...)` expansion, and would have suggested using `mapfile` instead (see [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2206)).

Also, note that you don't see the escape character in the suggested completions, but when you press `TAB` the shell will add it to the command. If you start your argument with quotes (either single or double), the shell will use quotes (the one you chose) instead of backslashes to protect the whitespaces. As long as `COMPREPLY` is built properly, this all comes for free, so there's no need to mangle the completion patterns.

---

As others pointed out, instead of as an escaped string, the command providing the expansion patterns could return them one per line (like e.g. `awk` or `ls`). As you now surely know, you can read the output into an array using `mapfile`:

```bash
mapfile -t my_array < <(the_command)
```

The problem is that `compgen` wants a string and not an array, so you need to expand it again, but you need to escape the whitespaces inside the single elements. This is probably the only tricky part of the whole process.

Fortunately, you can do array expansion and substring substitution at the same time:

```bash
"${my_array[*]// /\\ }"
```

and you can feed the result directly to `compgen`:

```bash
function _test() {
    local use cur
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    mapfile -t use < <(pink)
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(compgen -W "${use[*]// /\\ }" -- "$cur")
}
```

*Disclaimer*: I apologize for the many concepts here that are already present in the previous answers. I just wanted to stress that properly splitting the completions into the `COMPREPLY` array is the only requirement for tab completion. The shell takes care of everything after that, so it's not that difficult after all.
Moreover, as a teaching habit, I prefer to work out the problems in the OP's solution before providing a reference solution.